# C++ boost how to get a number of members in enum?

Tags: c++, boost

is there anything in the boost which could help to get a number of members in enumeration?

e.g. to return 3 for the following code:

```
enum SomeEnum
{
  One,
  Two,
  Three
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity - why it is important to know the number of "members" in enum?

Comment: Basically I am creating a map of enum members to names (using boost::assign::map_list_of. To make sure that I haven't missed any member in enum, I would like to compare the size of resulting map to the numbers of items in enumeration (each member in a map has a unique name).

Answer (score 6):

it's not totally obvious what you are asking for, but supposing you have an enum like:

```
enum Fruits
{
   Apples,
   Bananas,
   Pineapples,
   Oranges,
};
```

You could modify it like so:

```
enum Fruits
{
   Apples = 0,
   Bananas,
   Pineapples,
   Oranges,
   NUM_FRUITS; // must be last, and no other fruits can be given values. 
};
```

The `Apples = 0,` isn't strictly neccesary, it could still be just `Apples,` because that will be the result by default, but it's a good idea because it makes it clear that you actually *care* what value it takes.

And thus, `Fruits::NUM_FRUITS` would equal 4.  If you added two more fruits, being careful to place them *above* the `NUM_FRUITS`, and making sure the first fruit mentioned is set to zero, either implicitly or explicitly, then `NUM_FRUITS` will instead be 6.

Comment: +1 -- I think this is more consistent than Jason Iverson's answer -- unless one want to use his or her own `enum` values.

Answer (score 2):

I use

```
enum SomeEnum
{
  FIRST = 1,
  One   = 1,
  Two   = 2,
  Three = 3,
  LAST  = 3
}
```

Comment: Would it be `One = FIRST,` instead? If somebody later wants to add another enumerated value e.g. `Four = 4`, it must be remembered to change the `LAST = ` line to `4`. Though it sounds trivial, in reality, it turns out to be hard, i.e. easy to miss :)

Comment: I like that idea.  I'll try that with my next enum and see how it feels.

Comment: Just don't put the numbers in except FIRST = 0 and let the others go from there, that way if there are four items then LAST equals five, it is one more than the largest position which is easy to deal with and is nicer (IMO) in for loops if you prefer i < LAST rather than i <= LAST.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no general automatic solution after the enum's been created.  If you're prepared to force people to declare their enums via a macro, and your compiler supports variadic macros, you can have a macro that creates the enum and captures the number of elements (stringify, scan for commas ignoring whatevers inside pairs of < >, ( ), [ ] etc..